# Cannot delete data in solr 4.8.0

Tags: solr

I'm trying to delete a file from solr 4.8.0 using this query in my browser:

> httpProtocolHere://my.ip.v4.address:portNumber/solr/my_database/delete?q=field1%3Avalue1+AND+field2%3Avalue2+AND+field3%3Avalue3&wt=json&indent=true

When executing this query, only loading image is on the screen. And no log related to delete present in log files.

Any suggestions?

N.B. I'm newbie to solr.

Comment: Are you using an older version of the internet exploder?

Comment: @cheffe no. I'm using opera. on ubuntu 14.

Comment: Have you tried making the query with curl and see what the response code is, if any?

Comment: @No. Can you give me a hint on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HOST:PORT/solr/CORE/update?stream.body=<delete><query>field1:value1 AND field2:value2 AND field3:value3</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly!